# Unable to apply Cascading styles, when used JQuery locally rather than through CDN

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am a beginner in Android App Development using JQuery and am trying to put JQuery Scripts in local storage, rather than referring from Central Depository.

```
<script src="../www/js/jquery.1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="../www/js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../www/css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.2.css" />
```

But the desired output is not getting displayed. I also have the below code in index.html file.

```
<body>
 <div  data-role="page"> 
<div  data-role="header">Hello Android</div> 
<div  data-role="content">From Mani.</div> 
<div  data-role="footer">Test</div> 
</div> 
</body>
```

Plain text is displayed rather than with css elements. Checked in with previous posts regarding this question, and tried out some solutions, but they didn't work. Can someone please help..?

Comment: I'm assuming those aren't the correct urls. Check the network tab of your browser tools for errors.

Comment: Hi Jason, I am using emulator for android. So, I was checking in with Error Log in Eclipse.Didn't find any! Can you pls tell where you exactly referring to ..?

Comment: Ah, I missed the part about Android. Can't help you there. I would recommend adding appropriate Android tag(s) to your question.

Comment: Thanks ! Have added tags in question, to make it clear and reach to android community..! :)

Comment: You're not using JQM.css, you're using structure which works only with custom styles made by theme roller. You need to use jquery-mobile.1.3.2.css. Also, use jquery 1.9.2 not higher.

Comment: Thanks Omar..! Will check and get back to you..:)

Comment: @omar updated the answer..! the issue is due to phonegap method of referencing elements in absolute path, rather than relative method..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is due to the framework, which I used; Phonegap. It expects paths to be given in absolute manner.

**/android_asset/www/js/filename.js** , is the way one has to give the path, in order to have our element identified! :)